# Como fazer para um código javascript atualizar a hora direto do servidor?

Tags: javascript

Estou usando um código javascript que carrega a foto do locutor(a) de acordo com a data e a hora que ele está no ar. Gostaria que o código trocasse as imagens de acordo com a hora do MEU SERVIDOR e não do computador do usuário, para que as fotos também sejam exibidas corretamente em outro fuso horário. Como devo proceder? 
Segue abaixo o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

    function rodarImagens(){
            var current = new Date();
            var agora = current.getDay();
            var hora = current.getHours();
            var minutos = current.getMinutes();

            var locutor = document.getElementById('locutor');
switch (agora){
                    case 0: //domingo
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 6){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 6 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 18){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                    break
                    case 1: //segunda
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                    break
                    case 2: //terça

                    break        
                    case 3: //quarta

                    break
                    case 4: //quinta

                    break
                    case 5: //sexta

                    break                   
                    case 6: //sábado
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador .png"}
                            if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                            if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png"}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = 
"/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                    break   
            }
            setTimeout(function(){ rodarImagens() }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="rodarImagens()">
<img src="" id="locutor" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; 
z-index: 99999999;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O javascript é uma linguagem que roda direto no navegador do usuário , então você teria que puxar esta data de algum lugar como uma API ou ter essa data salva na sua pagina para que o script possa puxa-la. Talvez eu esteja errado e essa biblioteca possa te ajudar: https://github.com/NodeGuy/ServerDate

Comment: Qual a linguagem usada no site?

Comment: Estou usando o Joomla. PHP com base de dados MySQL.

Comment: Recomendo estudar Ajax e implementar no seu site. Se tiver alguma dúvida, pergunte aqui que teremos prazer em ajudar.

Comment: Dá uma ajeitada nesse tópico, que está dificil analisar o código. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o próprio php retornar a imagem e aplicar a lógica toda nele. Vou deixar abaixo um exemplo de como poderia ser feito.

> Arquivo que disponibiliza a imagem

```
<img src="#" alt="imagem locutor" id="locutor" />
<script>
    var intervaloAtualizaImagem = 60;
    function checarImagem() {
        var locutor = document.getElementById('locutor');
        locutor.src = 'carrega-imagem.php?hash=' + new Date().getTime();
        setTimeout(checarImagem, intervaloAtualizaImagem * 1000);
    }
    checarImagem();
    setTimeout(checarImagem, intervaloAtualizaImagem * 1000);
</script>
```

> Script **carrega-imagem.php**

```
<?php

// Representação numérica ISO-8601 do dia da semana (adicionado no PHP 5.1.0) / 1 (para Segunda) até 7 (para Domingo)
$dia = date('N');

// Representação da hora atual no formato 24-horas de uma hora com zero à esquerda
$hora = date('H');

// Minutos com zero à esquerda
$hora = date('i');

// identificando a imagem a ser exibida
switch($dia) {

    // segunda
    case 1:

        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // terça
    case 2: 
        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // quarta
    case 3: 
        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // quinta
    case 4: 
        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // sexta
    case 5: 
        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // sabado
    case 6: 
        if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png';
        if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png';
        if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png';
        if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24)
            $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
    // domingo
    case 7: 
        $imagem = __DIR__ . '/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png';
        break;
}

// informando tamanho do aquivo e não gerando cache
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-type: image/png");

// retornando a imagem
readfile($imagem);
```

> **Observação 1:** Esse código pode ser melhorado, caso você tenha um cadastro no banco de dados ele pode eliminar esse `switch` e pegar via SQL qual o operador do momento e já exibir a imagem.
>
> **Observação 2:** Com notei que a variação minima do tempo é em minutos eu aumentei o tempo de atualização para 60 segundos (1 minuto).
>
> **Observação 3:** Você precisa conferir se o caminho das imagens que eu coloquei no switch é o caminho real relativo ao seu script no servidor.

Answer (score -1):

O fato é que puxar em tempo real sem recarregar a página pode travar a Script se o servidor em questão cair, então eu vou mostrar como requisitar a data e hora por PHP com `AJAX` e sem o problema do `CACHE` e se o servidor vier a cair ele usará o não tentará puxar o tempo do servidor e sim do navegador evitando que a função pare de rodar Javascript.

Vamos criar um arquivo `PHP` que sempre gere o horário no mesmo formato que o `new Date()` de `Javascript`:
*realtime.php*

```
<?php
echo  "realtime = new Date('".date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s")."');";
?>
```

Agora você vai criar essa função chamada **realTime** acima da **rodarImagens**:

```
/* Iniciar variavel com tempo caso o servidor caia */
var realtime = new Date();

function clockServer(){
    nocache = nocache.getFullYear()+""+nocache.getMonth()+""+nocache.getDay()+nocache.getHours()+nocache.getMinutes()+nocache.getSeconds();

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            /*Requistar e executar resultado do JS dinâmico*/
            eval(xhttp.responseText);
        }
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404) {
            /*Caso o servidor caia*/
            realtime = new Date();
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "realtime.php?"+nocache, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Na função **rodaImagens** altere a primeira variavel para copiar uma variavel global que chamaremos te realttime (tempo real):

```
function rodarImagens(){
    var current = realtime;
    var agora = current.getDay();
    var hora = current.getHours();
    var minutos = current.getMinutes();
```

No final dessa mesmas função substitua por isso:

```
setTimeout(function(){ clockServer() }, 1200);
```

No código BODY do HTML substitua o chamado do onload por isto:

```
<body onload="clockServer()">
```

Mas em todo caso aconselho pegar o código modicado completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
/* Iniciar variavel com tempo caso o servidor caia */
var realtime = new Date();

function clockServer(){
 var nocache = new Date();
 nocache = nocache.getFullYear()+""+nocache.getMonth()+""+nocache.getDay()+nocache.getHours()+nocache.getMinutes()+nocache.getSeconds();

 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   /*Requistar e executar resultado do JS dinâmico*/
   eval(xhttp.responseText);
  }
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404) {
   /*Caso o servidor caia*/
   realtime = new Date();
  }
  rodarImagens();
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "realtime.php?"+nocache, true);
 xhttp.send();
}

function rodarImagens(){
 var current = realtime;
 var agora = current.getDay();
 var hora = current.getHours();
 var minutos = current.getMinutes();
 console.log(realtime);
    
 var locutor = document.getElementById('locutor');
 switch (agora){
  case 0: //domingo
   if(hora >= 0 && hora < 6){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 6 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 17 && hora < 18){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
  break
  case 1: //segunda
   if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
   if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
   if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
   if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
   if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src ="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
   if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
   if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
  break
  case 2: //terça

  break        
  case 3: //quarta

  break
  case 4: //quinta

  break
  case 5: //sexta

  break                   
  case 6: //sábado
   if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador .png"}
   if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
   if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png"}
   if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
   if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
  break
 }
 setTimeout(function(){ clockServer() }, 5000);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="clockServer()">
<img src="" id="locutor" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; 
z-index: 99999999;" />
</body>
</html>
  case 2: //terça

  break        
  case 3: //quarta

  break
  case 4: //quinta

  break
  case 5: //sexta

  break                   
  case 6: //sábado
   if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador .png"}
   if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
   if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
   if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png"}
   if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
   if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
  break
 }
 setTimeout(function(){ realTime() }, 1000);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="realTime()">
<img src="" id="locutor" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; 
z-index: 99999999;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Olha, se esse método não funcionar eu mando os arquivos prontos pra você, pois o código é grande e fica fácil de se perder.

Comment: 404 é erro de não encontrado em HTTP, o ideal seria verificar se é diferente do range de 200 e 299 dentro Ajax, por exemplo `if (this.readyState == 4) { return; } /*se não tiver concluido ainda */

if (this.status >= 200 || this.status < 300) {
    eval(xhttp.responseText);
} else {
    realtime = new Date();
}` ... outra sugestão é não usar o `eval`, simplesmente pegue o resultado da requisição HTTP assim `<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");` (o `?>` é dispensável/opcional em scripts PHP) e no Ajax faça isto:

Comment: `if (this.readyState !== 4) { return; } /*se não tiver concluido ainda */

if (this.status >= 200 || this.status < 300) {
    realtime = new Date(xhttp.responseText);
} else {
    realtime = new Date();
}`